# ajax nem submit funcionam em pagina carregada em .load()

Tags: php, html, ajax

ola pessoal tenho duas paginas mostra.php que contem algumas informações e a pagina 
index.php estou carregando a pagina mostra.php na pagina index.php com load da seguinte forma

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
         var linkado = "<?php echo $_GET['link'];?>"
    $("#carrinho").load('mostra.php?link='+linkado);
 });
```

na pagina mostra.php tem um form com um botão submit porem esse botão não funciona de forma, alguma segue a pagina mostra:

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);
ini_set(“display_errors”, 0 );

    ?>

        <?php
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['carrinho'])) {
        $_SESSION['carrinho'] = array();
    } //adiciona produto
    if (isset($_GET['acao'])) {
        //ADICIONAR CARRINHO
        if ($_GET['acao'] == 'add') {
            $id = intval($_GET['id']);
            if (!isset($_SESSION['carrinho'][$id])) {
                $_SESSION['carrinho'][$id] = 1;
            } else {
                $_SESSION['carrinho'][$id]+= 1;
            }
        } //REMOVER CARRINHO
        if ($_GET['acao'] == 'del') {
            $id = intval($_GET['id']);
            if (isset($_SESSION['carrinho'][$id])) {
                unset($_SESSION['carrinho'][$id]);
            }
        } //ALTERAR QUANTIDADE
        if ($_GET['acao'] == 'up') {
            if (is_array($_POST['prod'])) {
                foreach ($_POST['prod'] as $id => $qtd) {
                    $id = intval($id);
                    $qtd = intval($qtd);
                    if (!empty($qtd) || $qtd <> 0) {
                        $_SESSION['carrinho'][$id] = $qtd;
                    } else {
                        unset($_SESSION['carrinho'][$id]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $bdv = $_GET['link'];

    ?>

            <body>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header">
                                <h5 class="title">Edit Profile</h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="container">
                                    <table id="cart" class="table table-hover table-condensed">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th style="width:50%">Produto</th>
                                                <th style="width:10%" class="text-center">Quantidade</th>
                                                <th style="width:8%">Preço</th>
                                                <th style="width:22%" class="text-center">Subtotal</th>
                                                <th style="width:10%"> Remover</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
<!-- ESTE FORM QUE ESTOU ME REFERINDO -->
                                        <form name="post" id="cartadd" method="post">
                                            <tbody>
                                                <?php
    if (count($_SESSION['carrinho']) == 0) {
        echo '
            <tr>
              <td colspan="5">Não há produto no carrinho</td>
            </tr>
          ';
    } else {
        include "controller/conn/conncard.php"
    ?>
                                                    <?php
        $total = 0;
        foreach ($_SESSION['carrinho'] as $id => $qtd) {
            $sql = "SELECT *  FROM cadprod WHERE id_prod= '$id'";
            $qrs = mysqli_query($conn1, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn1));
            $lns = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qrs);
            $nome = $lns['nome_prod'];
            $preco = number_format($lns['preco_prod'], 2, ',', '.');
            $valor = $lns['preco_prod'];
            $sub = number_format($lns['preco_prod'] * $qtd, 2, ',', '.');
            $total+= $lns['preco_prod'] * $qtd;
                            echo '<tr>
                            <td data-th="Product">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <h4 class="nomargin">' . $nome . '</h4>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-center"> <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" name="prod[' . $id . ']" value="' . $qtd . '" /></td>
                                <td data-th="Quantity">R$ ' . $preco . '</td>
                                <td data-th="Subtotal" class="text-center">R$ ' . $sub . '</td>
                                <td class="actions" data-th="">
                                    <a  href="mostra.php?link=' . $bdv . '&acao=del&id=' . $id . '" class="pegaHref btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>                        
                                </td>
                            </tr>';
        }

         $subtotal = number_format($total, 2, '.', ',');

    }
        ?>
                                            </tbody>

                                            <tfoot>
                                                <tr class="visible-xs">
                                                    <td class="text-center"><strong>R$ <?php echo $subtotal; ?></strong></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><a href="cardapio.php?link=<?php echo $bdv; ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-md"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i> Continuar comprando</a></td>
                                                    <td colspan="2" class="hidden-xs"></td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <button id="submitform" type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">atualizar carriho</button>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td class="hidden-xs text-center"><strong>R$ <?php echo $subtotal; ?></strong></td>

                                                </tr>
                                            </tfoot>
                                        </form>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </body>

            <script>
               $(".pegaHref").click(function() {

        var href = this.href;

        $("#carrinho").fadeOut(500, function() {
            $("#carrinho").load(href).fadeIn().delay(500);

        });
        return false; // Impede a mudança de página  
    });


            </script>
```

ja tentei algumas formas como exemplo ajax para fazer funcionar

```
$('#submitform').on("click", function() {

            event.preventDefault();
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: $("form[name='post']").serialize(),
                url: "mostra.php?link=<?php echo $_GET['link'];?>&acao=up",
                success: function(resultado) {

                    $("#carrinho").fadeOut(500, function() {
                        $("#carrinho").load("mostra.php?link=<?php echo $_GET['link'];?>").fadeIn().delay(500);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

quando abro a pagina mostra php e coloco as bibliotecas la o codigo funciona normalmente mas quando abro o mostra.php no .load() da pagina index ele para de funcionar, nem o botão submit com action funciona alguem poderia me explicar onde estou errando?

Comment: Onde está essa parte `$('#submitform').on("click", function() {`? Já experimentou colocá-la antes de `$(".pegaHref").click(function() {`, no mesmo bloco `<script>`?

Comment: tentei porem não funcionou

Comment: Não é a solução do problema, mas ao carregar a página com .load(), retire as tags `<body>` e `</body>` da página carregada. O que tem que ser retornado é apenas o HTML dos elementos sem tags de estrutura de página, como o `<body>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não funciona porque você está colocando a tag `form` no lugar errado, entre a tag de fechamento `</thead>` e a tag de abertura `<tbody>`:

```
</thead>
<!-- ESTE FORM QUE ESTOU ME REFERINDO -->
<form name="post" id="cartadd" method="post">
<tbody>
```

Não pode colocar nenhum elemento entre as tags da estrutura de uma `table`. Com isso, o navegador irá fechar a tag `form` assim que ela é aberta, como mostra este print da ferramenta "inspecionar elementos":

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja que a tag `form` é fechada após a sua abertura, e o botão de submit não terá efeito algum, pois está fora do `form`.

Para resolver isto, coloque a tabela toda dentro do `form`:

```
<form name="post" id="cartadd" method="post">
   <table>
    ....conteúdo da tabela
   </table>
</form>
```

---

Outra coisa: retire da página requisitada as tags `<body>` e `</body>`. Embora não haja problemas nisso (porque o próprio navegador corrige, senão iriam ficar dois `<body>` na página), não é necessário carregar tags de estrutura de página no AJAX (o `.load()` é um AJAX), apenas o HTML de conteúdo que você deseja carregar (div, table, form, etc...).

Comment: funcionou mano valeu